# ActiveAdmin and CircleCI: autoloader causes Postgres to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activeadmin, circleci

We are using ActiveAdmin and CircleCI with Postgres and Rails 3.  It's been working fine, but after adding a new ActiveAdmin model, we get this during `rake db:create db:schema:load`:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "external_videos" does not exist
...
/home/ubuntu/Swearnet/app/models/external_video.rb:11:in `<class:ExternalVideo>'
/home/ubuntu/Swearnet/app/models/external_video.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
/home/ubuntu/Swearnet/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
/home/ubuntu/Swearnet/app/admin/external_video.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
/home/ubuntu/Swearnet/config/routes.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

And if we remove the new file (even though this file is not substantially different than any other of our ActiveAdmin files), the error goes away.

This error appear to be that the routes cause ActiveAdmin to load, which causes the ExternalVideo model to be autoloaded, which causes it to look for the external_videos table that has not been created yet.  Why doesn't this happen for our other ActiveAdmin files?  Has anyone else hit this sort of problem before?

Our new file is `app/admin/external_videos.rb` and looks like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ExternalVideo do
  menu :parent => "Shows"

  form do |f|
    f.inputs nil do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
      f.input :published_at
      f.input :expires_at
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** we have found the problem... there was a scope on ExternalVideo named `find_by_sxg_id`.  When we rename that scope to `get_by_sxg_id` then everything works.  I'm at a loss...  I know that `find_by` is normally a magic ActiveRecord prefix, but not sure how the mere definition caused the table to be accessed before it was created in the rake task...

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of anyone looking for a bit more information, I hope this information helps. In the context of activeadmin, there were two places where we ran into this problem.

**1. Failing to declare a proc {} when defining a collection on a search filter.**

For example:

```
filter :association_id, as: :select, collection: Association.all, label: "Association"
```

should be

```
filter :association_id, as: :select, collection: proc { Association.all }, label: "Association"
```

Doing defers the model load until the index page is actually loaded and allows Circle CI to complete the db:schema:load (or the rake task which does the db:schema:load)

**2. Registering a resource loads the model definition and as such if there are any method definitions that require instantiation of the model, Circle CI will give you that Postgres error and you won't get anywhere.**

This was the trickier one to find although in hindsight it should have been obvious. So, for instance if you have a "roll-your-own" state machine with states "initial, active, inactive" and you wanted to define a set of query methods, you might do this:

```
def states
  [ :initial, :active, :inactive ]
end

def self.included(Model)
  states = Model.new.states
  states.each do |state|
  base.send(:define_method, "#{state}?") do
    self.state == state
end
```

So in order to even load the resource, we need to instantiate the model (the Model.new line). To fix this, we changed it to:

```
def self.states
  [ :initial, :active, :inactive ]
end

def self.included(Model)
  states = Model.states
  states.each do |state|
  base.send(:define_method, "#{state}?") do
    self.state == state
end
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem when using ActiveRecord, and you're not the first to have this bug! It's so common we wrote a doc on it: https://circleci.com/docs/ruby-exception-during-schema-load

Comment: I have of course seen that doc.  The question is: how is it that the mere name of a scope caused this issue?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's a tiny bit unclear. Using the name in activerecord loads the model, and the model relies on database schema introspection. Since the DB isn't there, it breaks. Make sense?